# SQLite AVG() returns same result as row

Tags: sql, sqlite, average, aggregate-functions

While using `AVG()` to figure out the average mark of a student, I noticed that my result is the same as the input per row.

For example:

[image: AVG() result]

in the image above, Jeff has `83` and `85` for term 2 and 3, but his `avg_mark` is not a single row that says `83.5`

My query is as follows:

```
Select m.stdName, m.markPercent, m.crsName, m.term, AVG(distinct markPercent)  as avg_mark 
from Marks as m 
inner join StudentSchedule as ss on ss.crsName = m.crsName and ss.stdName = m.stdName
Inner JOIn Course as c on c.crsName = m.crsName
where m.stdName like 'Jeff'
group by m.stdName, m.markPercent, m.crsName, m.term;
```

Some tables from my schema:

```
create table Course (
  crsID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT,
  crsName VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  crsTerm INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE StudentSchedule(
  stdSchedule INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT,
  stdName INT NOT NULL,
  teacherName INT not NULL,
  crsName INT not NULL,
  startTime NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  endTime NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  term INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(stdName) references Student(stdID),
  FOREIGN KEY(teacherName) REFERENCES Teacher(teacherID),
  FOREIGN KEY(crsName) REFERENCES Course(crsID)
);

CREATE TABLE Marks (
  markID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  markPercent REAL NOT NULL,
  stdName INT NOT NULL,
  crsName INT not NULL,
  term INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(stdName) references Student(stdID),
  FOREIGN KEY(crsName) REFERENCES Course(crsID),
  FOREIGN KEY(term) references StudentSchedule(term)
);

insert into Course (crsName, crsTerm) values ('COMP4900', 2);

insert into StudentSchedule(stdName, teacherName, crsName, startTime, endTime, term) values ('Jeff','tej','COMP4900',1000,1200,2);
insert into StudentSchedule(stdName, teacherName, crsName, startTime, endTime, term) values ('Jeff','farnaz','COMP4900',1200,200,3);

insert into Marks (markPercent, stdName, crsName, term) values (83.0, 'Jeff','COMP4900', 2);
insert into Marks (markPercent, stdName, crsName, term) values (87.0, 'Jeff','COMP4900', 3);
```

Could anyone point out a flaw in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is a little confusing because `stdName` and `crsName` are integers but your INSERTs are putting strings in them (which unfortunately SQLite lets you get away with).

That aside, the main problem is that you're grouping by `m.markPercent` and several other things so you end up applying the aggregate function to one row at a time. There's also the odd `AVG(distinct markPercent)` which doesn't make much sense, the GROUP BY problem hides this issue.

You'd be better off building your averages in a derived table and joining to that. The averages you're after can be computed with:

```
select stdName, avg(markPercent) avgMark
from Marks
group by stdName, crsName
```

You're after the student's average in each course and that's exactly what that says. Use that as a derived table and join to it:

```
select m.stdName, m.markPercent, m.crsName, m.term, a.avgMark
from Marks m
join (select stdName, avg(markPercent) avgMark from Marks group by stdName, crsName) a on m.stdName = a.stdName
where ...
```

Then, if `stdName` and `crsName` really are integers that reference other tables, then more joins to get the actual string names you want.

Comment: You could also point out that `AVG(DISTINCT)` is basically never going to be the right thing to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff True, I missed that one.